# Alert if file grows more than a certain size in 5 minutes

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to write a script to check how much a file has grown in the last 5 minutes, and write out to a log if it grows more than 20MB in that time.

So far I've managed to write this;

```
output="$HOME/log/logsize.output"                       # This file is where the values are written to before being compared
currentsize=$(stat '-c%s' "$HOME/log/input.log")        # This is the current size of the log file

    echo $currentsize >> $output

oldsize=$(sed 'x;$!d' < "$output")                      # Sets the previous reading as "oldsize" by pulling the second to last line of $output
difference=$(("$currentsize" - "$oldsize"))             # This is the difference in size between the current and previous readings


if $difference > "1999999"                              # Checks the difference, if greater than 1999999 write an error.
    then
    echo "Warning! Log File has exceeded the expected rate of growth. Please investigate." > "$HOME/log/logalert.log"
else
    echo "Log File is within expected parameters" > "$HOME/log/logalert.log"
fi
```

When I run this script this is the output I recieve;

```
line 23: "2910" - "2910": syntax error: operand expected (error token is ""2910" - "2910"")
```

Solved!

Here's what I did in the end to get this working

```
#!/bin/bash
#########################################################################
# Author - Jack Arnold
#
# Last Updated: 20.02.18
#########################################################################
#
# This script exists to periodically check the file size of a log file.
# If this file has grown 20MB or more since the last loop of this script
# it will write out an alert to ~/logs/logsize.log
#
#########################################################################


# Variables for the script.

output="$HOME/log/logsize.output"                       # This file is where the values are written to before being compared
currentsize=$(stat '-c%s' "$HOME/log/input.log")        # This is the current size of the log file

    echo "$currentsize" >> "$output"

oldsize=$(sed 'x;$!d' < "$output")                      # Sets the previous reading as "oldsize" by pulling the second to last line of $output
difference=$((currentsize - oldsize))                   # This is the difference in size between the current and previous readings


if [[ $difference > "1999999" ]]                        # Checks the difference, if greater than 1999999 write an error.
    then
    echo "Warning! Log File has exceeded the expected rate of growth. Please investigate." > "$HOME/log/logalert.log"
else
    echo "Log File is within expected parameters" > "$HOME/log/logalert.log"
fi
```

Comment: Copy paste your script on https://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix the errors shown

Comment: Short answer from shellcheck: `"~/file"` is something different than `~"/file"`. You probably wanted to use `~` without quotes.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't heard of that website before. Really useful utility.

Comment: I've fixed all the errors according to shellcheck. I'm now turning up an error for my stat command.

    "stat" - "stat": syntax error: operand expected (error token is ""stat" - "stat"")

Not sure what could be causing this, as running the command in the shell works as expected. I imagine it's some escape char i'm missing?

currentsize=(stat "-c%s" "$HOME/log/input.log")

Comment: @JackArnold Please edit your answer so that we can see the whole script. The things you fixed are no longer of interest. Just overwrite them. I think you wanted to write `currentsize=$(...)` instead of `=(...)` but that doesn't explain the error.

Comment: Updated the post now

Comment: The error message doesn't look consistent with your [mcve].  I can't even see line 23.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing I noticed was that in the very first line, the variable assignment (`output="~/log/logsize.output"`) would cause problems as `~` is not expanded in quotes. However, there are a *lot more* errors in this script and I’d advise spending more time learning the basics of shell scripting; I’d suggest [Greg’s Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) as a great starting point.

A [while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13730169), I updated the *usage guidance* for the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) tag so that it includes the advice to check shell scripts in https://www.shellcheck.net/ which is a fabulous resource. Indeed, Shellcheck warns about the tilde issue and includes the useful suggestion of using `$HOME` instead of `~`.  Rather than re-iterating *all* the issues that Shellcheck would warn you about, I’ll just mention some of the problems that it doesn’t pick up on:

#### Command substitution

```
currentsize=(stat '-c%s' "~/log/input.log")
```

I imagine you intend to use command substitution so that the `currentsize` variable contains the output of the `stat` command. This should be written as:

```
currentsize=$(stat '-c%s' "$HOME/log/input.log")
```

#### Arithmetic comparisons

Shellcheck stops processing before it gets to this line but I notice that you are using `>` as an arithmetic comparison operator:

```
if (${difference} > 1999999) ;
```

In POSIX (standard for Unix-like operating systems) shells, these operators are used for input and output redirection – as you’ve done in

```
echo "Log File is within expected parameters" > "~/log/logalert.log"
```

The correct operator for arithmetic comparisons in POSIX shells is `-gt` and the *portable* way to test this is:

```
if [ "$difference" -gt 1999999 ]
```

Note: Shells such as `bash` and `ksh` extend POSIX by using `<` and `>` for arithmetic comparisons but this only applies within *double* parentheses. See [Comparing integers: arithmetic expression or conditional expression](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278798/22812). In Bash, the `>` can also be used for string comparisons when used with the `[[` construct.  See [Bash Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions).

Also: you only really need to quote strings if they contain unusual characters that are specially interpreted by the shell (e.g., spaces result in word-splitting).  However, there’s no harm in doing so if you’re already used to it from using other programming languages and you find it to be more readable.

#### General tips

- Always quote variable expansions (except when you explicitly require word-splitting)
- Use `set -x` when debugging.
- `set -e` is also useful to get notified of errors such as attempting to access the contents of a non-existent variable.

Comment: Bah! I started composing this answer before any of the comments were posted or before question was edited.

Comment: Thank you anyway @Anthony Geohegan, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just wanted to offer my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

output="$HOME/log/logsize.output"
if [ ! -f $HOME/log/logsize.output ]
then
    touch $HOME/log/logsize.output
fi

while [ 1 ]
do
    stat '-c%s' $HOME/log/input.log >> "${output}"
    math=$(tail -n2 "${output}" | tr '\n' '-' | sed 's/.$//g')
# 20971520 bytes is 20 Mbytes. Uncomment this string, and comment mine with -100 argument. Mine string is only for the example.
#   if [ $(($math)) -lt -20971520 ]
    if [ $(($math)) -lt -100 ]
    then
        echo "Attemption! The file have has grown by more then 20Mbytes!"
    fi
# Replace sleep 5 by sleep 600 for 1 per 5 minute check.
sleep 5
done
```

You can run it as you wish: `./filechange.sh &` or in cron (if you wish cron, remove `while` loop and `sleep`)
How does it works:

```
$ ls -l
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sahaquiel sahaquiel 400 Feb 20 15:00 filechange.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 sahaquiel sahaquiel   0 Feb 20 14:58 input.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sahaquiel sahaquiel   0 Feb 20 14:59 logsize.output
$ ./filechange.sh & 
[1] 29829
# Adding 150 random numbers in input.log file
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC log]$ i=0; while [ $i -lt 150 ]; do echo $RANDOM >> input.log; i=$(($i + 1)); done
# filechange.sh echo in my shell:
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC log]$ Attemption! The file have has grown by more then 20Mbytes!

$ ls -l
total 12
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sahaquiel sahaquiel 400 Feb 20 15:00 filechange.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 sahaquiel sahaquiel 849 Feb 20 15:00 input.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 sahaquiel sahaquiel  14 Feb 20 15:00 logsize.output
```